# Airflow falls with TypeError "can't pickle module objects" when task returns kwargs

Tags: python, airflow

Why airflow falls with `TypeError: can't pickle module objects` when task `returns kwargs` with `provide_context= True`?

But when I do `print kwargs` in same task - then everything is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is most likely something in the kwargs object. The error arises because when you return from an operator in airflow it is saved in the airflow database as part of the xcom set up.

I would suggest you take a look at what's in your kwargs and figure out which items are "module objects" rather than more trivial data types. A simple way around the problem itself would be to only return the things you need to return, rather than the whole kwargs object.